# How to understand zone by MOMENT.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have problem with String > Format of timezone.
I have string: " 2015-02-10 00:00:00,3,UTC "
And try to format it in moment:

```
moment('2015-02-10 00:00:00,3,UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss, ?, ?')
```

What should I insert instead of "?"

Comment: what is the 3? for the second ? you have to put z

Comment: 3 it's timezone. For moment it should look like +03:00 or +0300, not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to format that kind of string into moment because a lone `3` does not designate the timezone offset in any standard format.

You need to change the 3 into `+0030`.

This should work:

```
var date = '2015-02-10 00:00:00,3,UTC'
.replace(/,(\d\d),/,',+$100,') // for double digit cases (11 turns to +1100)
.replace(/,(\d),/,',+0$100,'); // single digit cases (3 to +0300)
```

And then

```
moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,ZZ')
```

I'm not sure what the UTC part is about since `+0300` is clearly not UTC. I guess it's just saying that the the 3 hour offset is relative to UTC?